# dport is not working on iptables command

Tags: firewall, iptables

In terminal I type :

```
iptables -A INPUT --dport 443 -j DROP
```

And it tells me :

```
iptables v1.4.21: unknown option "--dport"
```

what is wrong with `--dport`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to first identify the protocol, for example TCP or UDP. You do that by using the `-p <protocol>` option.

I'm assuming you want TCP, so your iptables command should look like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
```